# Unforgiving GCC C++ compiler

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, compiler-construction

MS VS x86 compiler has no problem with the following definitions, but GCC (ARM) complains. Is GCC dumb or is MSVS_x86 too clever?

```
bool checkPointInside(const CIwVec2& globalPoint) {
    return checkPointIn(globalPoint, CIwVec2());
}; /// error: no matching function for call to 'Fair::Sprite::checkPointIn(const CIwVec2&, CIwVec2)'

bool checkPointIn(const CIwVec2& globalPoint, CIwVec2& localPoint) {
    return false;
};
```

Comment: x86 is a CPU architecture, not a compiler. Please fix your terminology, the question is a bit confusing this way.

Comment: MS x86 = MS VS x86 compiler = Microsoft Visual Studio x86 compiler. Hope that's clear enough now :-)

Comment: If "too clever" is what you call it when a bunch of the smartest computer scientists get together, studies a problem, decides that there's a very good reason not to allow binding non-const references to temporaries, makes it an error, standardizes the error, and then Microsoft ignores both the wisdom and the standard and allows it anyway, then yes, the MS compiler is "too clever".  (I love just about everything else about the VC++ compiler, but this is broken)

Comment: Common practice will always better the smartest computer scientists' theories. Don't want to start a flame war here, just saying that if VC++ allows this, then it has proved itself harmless all these years. Or has it..?

Comment: @Bill: I disagree. Binding non-const references to rvalues is both useless and harmful.

Comment: @FredOverflow : Can you elaborate on the harmful nature of this please?

Comment: @Bill: Passing by non-const reference implies that a function mutates the objects provided by the client, and the client expects to be able to observe those changes. However, observing the changes is impossible if you pass rvalues. That's why it would not make any sense to pass an rvalue to a function by non-const reference. The fact that Microsoft allows this can lead to a) long debugging sessions and b) nonportable code.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Passing temporary to non-const reference argument does make sense in some cases. Most notably when the function returns the reference back. E.g. A very useful construction `static_cast<stringstream>(stringstream() << something).str())` makes perfect sense, but does not work because temporaries can't be bound to non-const references. It can be worked around in this case by `static_cast<stringstream>(stringstream().flush() << something).str()`, because non-const methods can be called on temporaries.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the C++ standard, you cannot bind an rvalue to a non-const reference. The Microsoft compiler has an evil extension that allows this, however. So g++ is correct not to accept your program.

Comment: They call it an "extension", but actually it's a bug.

Comment: @sbi: Why ? I would call it an extension too. We do call VLA extensions after all. As for the "binding" issue... I never understood why one could bind to `const` and not to a plain reference. And I do find the actual "correctness" enforcement argument bogus.

Comment: @Mat: Bjarne was bitten by it on occasion, so he banned it. Simple as that.

Comment: g++ saved me from countless bugs by disallowing this.

Answer (score 8):

g++ is right to complain and Microsoft has this wrong.  The problem with this code is that the checkPointIn function takes it's second parameter by reference, meaning that it must take an lvalue (a variable, or a dereferenced pointer, for example).  However, the code in checkPointInside is passing in a temporary object, which is an rvalue.  For historical reasons the Microsoft compiler allows this, though it's explicitly forbidden by the spec.  Usually, if you crank the warning level all the way up in the Microsoft compiler, it will indeed flag this code as erroneous.

To fix this, either have checkPointIn take its last argument by value or by const reference.  The latter is probably the better choice, since const references can bind to rvalues if necessary and avoid making costly copies in other cases.

Comment: The temporary object is not an rvalue. The *expression* `CIwVec2()` is.

Answer (score 4):

You can't create references to temporaries (only constant references or r-value references in C++0x).

This is happening when you call `checkPoint` with `CIwVec2()` as second parameter.

Comment: Just to be clear:  you *can* create `const` references to temporaries, but not normal, mutable, references.  I recently spent a few days rooting out this kind of code in an old DLL at work.

Comment: You can't... except in Microsoft ignore-the-standard mode.

Comment: Actually, it is totally possible to create (dangling) references to temporaries: `std::string& r = std::string("hello").append("world");`. That's because in this case the expression denoting the temporary is an lvalue instead of an rvalue.