# A library "misbehaved" with a pass by reference, and it should not have compiled, why did it compile?

Tags: c++

I was using yaml-cpp, a yaml parsing library, and I was turning crazy because my yaml document was not being parsed entirely. Turns out it's because a constructor should have been given a reference, and not an object.

incorrect code :

```
ifstr;
YAML::Parser parser(ifstream("items9.yml"));
```

correct code :

```
ifstream ifstr("items9.yml");
YAML::Parser parser(ifstr);
```

The person told me it should not have compiled, I'm using visual C++ 10. Is this normal behaviour and should I be aware of it, or is the library wrongly designed or visual C++ wrongly accepting the code ?

Comment: Is there a YAML::Parser constructor that accepts R-Value reference (std::ifstream&&)? If yes it should compile just fine

Comment: I was being told it's about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032756/unforgiving-gcc-c-compiler

Comment: anyway I don't think there is such constructor

Comment: You are being told correct. You are passing an rvalue where an lvalue is expected. The ifstream() constructed in the first example is a temporary.

Comment: @gokoon: If you're using the Visual C++ compiler, compile with `/W4` and `/WX` and see what errors you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known *issue* in VS, that (unlike the standard) allows binding of non-const references to rvalues. The same can be tested with this code:

```
struct test {};
test f() { return test(); }
int main() {
   test & r = f();          // Should be an error
}
```

Comment: If you select the proper warning level (/W4), you get a message `warning C4239: nonstandard extension used : 'initializing' : conversion from 'test' to 'test &' X:\reference\TEST.cpp 4`